# change y-axis limits timePlot

Tags: r

I am using the function `timePlot` (from openair), and I wanted to fix the limits of the y-axis. For that, I should select `auto.text=FALSE`, but I don't know how to specify the values for each specie. For instance:

```
      require(openair)

      timePlot(selectByDate(mydata, year = 1998, month = 1), pollutant =
               + c("nox", "no2"), 
               y.relation="free",lwd = c(1, 2),lty=c(1,1),auto.text=FALSE)
```

So, if I want to define the limits for nox let's say, 0 500 and for no2 0,80.. (just to change the values), how could I do that?
Any suggestion??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `mydata`? This is not reproducible.

Comment: @nrussell `mydata` is actually reproducible in this case. It comes with the package -- `data(mydata)` LOL. This is the 1 time out of a million when sometime says "mydata" and it's actually something reproducible.

Comment: @Hack-R Then the OP should include this in the question...

Comment: @nrussell ok, I submitted another edit that adds it

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to plot them one at a time then you can pass the `ylim` option from `lattice`:

```
require(openair)
data(mydata)
timePlot(selectByDate(mydata, year = 1998, month = 1), pollutant = c("nox"), y.relation="free",
         lwd = c(1, 2),lty=c(1,1),auto.text=FALSE, ylim = c(0, 500)) 

timePlot(selectByDate(mydata, year = 1998, month = 1), pollutant = c("no2"), y.relation="free",
         lwd = c(1, 2),lty=c(1,1),auto.text=FALSE, ylim = c(0, 80))
```

Comment: thanks, I see..however, there is no option to specify this in the same timePlot? because I want to plot several species in the same plot (to compare them), and it is quite annoying if I have to write every time timePlot (for each one)

Comment: There's not an option for that and `ylim` can only be accepted 1x in `timePlot` with a length of 2 -- though you could get the source code for this function and re-write it a bit. Personally, I'd just copy and paste the `timePlot` function, changing the limits/pollutant for each plot, and then combine them after the fact however you like them, either in R or much better in an image editing program like GIMP.